# Getting MAX Value of a Field for INSERT Statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert a new record in a small settings table and I would like to get the MAX value of the DisplayOrder field and add 10 to it.  I get errors with the MAX function in the value of the insert.

```
INSERT INTO tMrMenu
       ([ParentId]
       ,[DisplayOrder]
       ,[ItemName]
       ,[ItemDescription]
       ,[ItemURL]
       ,[ItemImage]
       ,[CreateDate]
       ,[CreateUser]
       ,[LastUpdateDate]
       ,[LastUpdateUser]
       ,[module]
       ,[isactive])
 SELECT
        ( 1
        , (SELECT MAX(DisplayOrder) + 10 FROM tMrMenu)
        , 'EDM Summary Text'
        , 'EDM Summary Text'
        , '/Offline/Reports/EdmSummaryText'
        , 'cli.gif'
        , GETDATE()
        , 'Garry.Bargsley'
        , GETDATE()
        , 'Garry.Bargsley'
        , 'MR'
        , 1)
```

Comment: You are hopefully aware that this "technique" is very much prone to duplicates under heavy usage load... if multiple clients read the current `MAX(DisplayOrder)` at the same time, and each increase it by 10, several inserts with the same, new value might occur.

Answer (score 1):

You have extra parenthesis:

```
INSERT INTO tMrMenu
       ([ParentId]
       ,[DisplayOrder]
       ,[ItemName]
       ,[ItemDescription]
       ,[ItemURL]
       ,[ItemImage]
       ,[CreateDate]
       ,[CreateUser]
       ,[LastUpdateDate]
       ,[LastUpdateUser]
       ,[module]
       ,[isactive])
 SELECT
        1
        , (SELECT MAX(DisplayOrder) + 10 FROM tMrMenu)
        , 'EDM Summary Text'
        , 'EDM Summary Text'
        , '/Offline/Reports/EdmSummaryText'
        , 'cli.gif'
        , GETDATE()
        , 'Garry.Bargsley'
        , GETDATE()
        , 'Garry.Bargsley'
        , 'MR'
        , 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @max int
SET @max = (SELECT MAX...)

INSERT INTO tMrMenu...
SELECT
...
@max,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tMrMenu
       ([ParentId]
       ,[DisplayOrder]
       ,[ItemName]
       ,[ItemDescription]
       ,[ItemURL]
       ,[ItemImage]
       ,[CreateDate]
       ,[CreateUser]
       ,[LastUpdateDate]
       ,[LastUpdateUser]
       ,[module]
       ,[isactive])
SELECT MAX(DisplayOrder) + 10 
        , 'EDM Summary Text'
        , 'EDM Summary Text'
        , '/Offline/Reports/EdmSummaryText'
        , 'cli.gif'
        , GETDATE()
        , 'Garry.Bargsley'
        , GETDATE()
        , 'Garry.Bargsley'
        , 'MR'
        , 1
FROM tMrMenu
```